# Discord.js reply to interaction with "only you can see this" message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

In discord.js I'm trying to reply to an interaction using `interaction.reply({content: "test"})`, but I couldn't figure out how to send an "only you can see this" message.

Example:

[image]

I am using discord.js v13

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are called ephemeral responses, and you can send them by using `ephemeral: true` in the `reply`'s [`InteractionReplyOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions), like this:

```js
interaction.reply({ content: 'Only you! :)', ephemeral: true });
```

This way the message is hidden from everyone but the executor of the slash command.